# Xamarin 4.0.13 Layout Renderer failed

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I get the error "Connection to the layout renderer failed. This may be caused by a misconfiguration of Java. Please close and open the file again" after update to 4.0.13. This is error log:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\ant-tasks.jar;C:\Program
ERROR [2013-10-13 10:47:56Z]: Connection failed
System.Exception: Java process failed to start
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.JavaProcessConnection.DoConnect()
ERROR [2013-10-13 10:47:58Z]: Could not update jumplists
System.InvalidOperationException: The file type is not registered with this application.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.JumpList.AppendCustomCategories()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.JumpList.Refresh()
   at MonoDevelop.Platform.JumpList.UpdateJumpList()
   at MonoDevelop.Platform.JumpList.OnUpdateTimerEllapsed(Object sender, EventArgs args)
```

Xamarin should test carefully before release update package. I wish I didn't update to 4.0.13.

Comment: Solution is reinstall 4.0.12 update package which was located at C:\Users[Your User name]\AppData\Local\XamarinStudio-4.0\Cache\TempDownload.

Comment: I am having the very same issue but don't have the older update package... So what do I do now?

Comment: You can download from here:
http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Windows/XamarinStudio-4.0.12-3.msi

Comment: possible duplicate of ["layout renderer failed" error in xamarin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426993/layout-renderer-failed-error-in-xamarin)

Comment: If you are getting this issue at the start of 2015 the resolution seems to be uninstall pre 1.8 JDKs and install JDK 1.8 64 bit. http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30818/connection-to-the-layout-renderer-failed-after-updating-to-5-7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426993/layout-renderer-failed-error-in-xamarin/28276331#28276331

Answer (score 0):

I think this was resolved. for me I kept getting this error randomly but if you face it just open android sdk manager from visual studio
TOOLS > ANDROID > Android SDK Manager

Comment: And then? after opening Android SDK Manager, what should I do?