# "layout renderer failed" error in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have a sample **Android** project which is working well (can be built and installed on mobile phone). But whenever I double click on any file in the `Layout` folder in xamarin environment to see the layout in design mode, the following message appears. (my xamarin version is 4.0.13)

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341726/xamarin-4-0-13-layout-renderer-failed) question but no answer was provided. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I was going to post the same question now..:)

Comment: If you are getting this issue at the start of 2015 the resolution seems to be uninstall pre 1.8 JDKs and install JDK 1.8 64 bit. http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30818/connection-to-the-layout-renderer-failed-after-updating-to-5-7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426993/layout-renderer-failed-error-in-xamarin/28276331#28276331

Answer (score 4):

Xamarin team have identified an issue with this in 4.0.13 and are working on a fix for it at the moment

[Link](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2594/connection-to-the-layout-renderer-failed-after-today-s-update)

Until this is in place, the only way to get the renderer working is to uninstall 4.0.13 and re-install 4.0.12

Answer (score 1):

Known bug(https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=18193). Solution here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14344/disconnected-from-layout-renderer-error-after-updating-android-sdk-tools-to-version-22-6

Answer (score 1):

This same error message now appears for a new issue as of Jan 2015.

["layout renderer failed" error in xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426993/layout-renderer-failed-error-in-xamarin)

The issue is around Xamarin now expecting a 64 bit JDK and using a 32 bit JDK.  The fix is to uninstall JDK 1.6 or 1.7 and install 1.8 64 Bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a temporary solution to this. I closed the layout tab, then removed two processes from task manager:
MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.exe and mandroid.exe
and I was able to open layout again. But it doesnt fix the problem :>