# Xamarin MonoDroid does not support running the previous version

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have just installed the Xamarin tools, installation went without any errors.

I have launched VS 2013 Update 4 Pro and created Blank App ( Native Shared ).

I did not modify code or project structure, just tried to run.

So i have changed the Startup Project to Adnroid project:

[image]

Then i have rebuilt the entire solution.
The console prompted Rebuild succeeded.

I have noticed that debugging button has a very long path, which is strange:

[image]

If i click on any option it opens the AVD Manager, but doesn't change the Start, to selected device.

So i have tried launching the Emulator from AVD manager and it works.

But when i click start in VS it prompts me:

[image]

Where is the problem? How can a newly installed app not work?

Comment: Is you project targeting lower android API?

Comment: Milen, please post an answer so i could accept it. Really, setting the properties of the project did the trick

Comment: See this answer [Build Failed. MonoDroid does not support running the previous version][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581863/build-failed-monodroid-does-not-support-running-the-previous-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You project is most likely targeting lower version of android API. Try changing the target android version.

Answer (score 0):

A note here should be that within Visual Studio/Xamarin the settings regarding supported version are within the solution settings of that project.

In this way you can change the version to support what you need, or if it is correct download a more current simulator.

This can be done with [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) for instance or [Xamarin Android Player](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-player/).